# How to find the $x$ values of $2\cos(2x)-2\sin(x)=0$?

Tags: calculus, roots

I am not sure how to find the $x$ values of $2\cos(2x)-2\sin(x)=0$.

I am trying to find the absolute values of $f(x)=2\cos(x)+\sin(2x)$ in the range$[0, \frac{\pi}{2}]$.

I have differentiated $f(x)$ to produce $2\cos(2x)-2\sin(x)$, but I am unsure how to find the zeros of the function since I cannot think of a value of $x$ that would make both sine and cosine equal 0.

$$\frac{d}{dx} 2\cos(x)=[0 \cdot \cos(x)] + [2 \cdot -\sin(x)]=-2\sin(x)$$
$$\frac{d}{dx}\sin(2x)= \cos(2x) (2)=2\cos(2x)$$

$$\frac{d}{dx}2\cos(x)+\sin(2x)=2\cos(2x)-2\sin(x)$$

Comment: Have you tried using the cos(2x) identity to get everything in the form of sin(x)

Comment: @rhombicosicodecahedron I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: $Cos(2x) = 1-2sin^2(x)$ solution will further involve substitution

Comment: @rhombicosicodecahedron I have tried that just now. It gets me $2-4\sin^2(x)-\sin(x)=0$, but I'm not sure how to deal with the $2$.

Comment: try $\frac{pi}{2}$ for 2cos(x)+sin(2x)

Comment: Do you know how to solve quadratic equations?

Comment: @LeeMosher not with trig functions.

Comment: $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin^2(x).$

Comment: You wrote an equation in your comment, $2 - 4 \sin^2(x) - \sin(x)=0$ (but you should check that for correctness). Can you make a substitution which converts that into a quadratic equation?

Comment: @LeeMosher I can't think of a trig identity which would let me get rid of the trig functions.

Comment: You might get a hint by reading some of the answers posted below.

Comment: @LeeMosher I have, I don't understand any of them. except for the one that says "hint.."

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any calculus to do this:
$$ 0=2\cos(2x)-2\sin(x) = 2(\cos^2x -\sin^2x -\sin x) = 2(1-\sin x - 2\sin^2x). $$
which is a quadratic equation (substitute $y=\sin x$).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:......
$$\cos2x=1-2\sin^2x$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $s:=\sin x$ so $\sin x-\cos 2x=2s^2+s-1$, which $=0$ for $s\in\{-1,\,\frac12\}$. For $x\in[0,\,\frac{\pi}{2}]$, only $s=\frac12$ is obtainable, viz. $x=\frac{\pi}{6}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

Rewrite the equation as $\;\cos(2x)=\cos \bigl(\frac\pi 2-x\bigr)$.

Then use that $$\cos\alpha=\cos\beta\iff \alpha\equiv\pm\beta \pmod{2\pi}.$$